# Is there such a thing as a て particle?

Tags: particles, verbs

While browsing through some chapters of the Bleach manga, I stumbled over a sentence that puzzles me. A chapter is called:

立ちて死すべし

I know what 立ち means and I know that the べし is a suffix that kind of means that the verb is an obligation or something that should be done(?). But I can't make sense of the て kana and why it is 死す and not 死ぬ.

Link to where it appeared is [here](http://bleach.wikia.com/wiki/THE_FIRE#cite_note-trans-2), chapter 511.

Would a correct translation be "those who stand shall/must die"?

Comment: 立ち→ http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A4 、 て→ http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%A6 → 接続助詞、　死す→ http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E6%AD%BB%E3%81%99 、　べし→ http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%B9%E3%81%97

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 立ちて死すべし

The 立ち is the continuative form (連用形) of the archaic verb [立つ](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A4).
The て is the conjunctive particle (接続助詞), i.e. 立ちて is the te-form of 立つ in Classical Japanese.
[死す](http://kobun.weblio.jp/content/%E6%AD%BB%E3%81%99) is a literary, bookish way of saying 死ぬ. As in @broccoliforest's comment below 死す is the archaic form of [死する](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/96874/meaning/m0u/).

So in modern Japanese I think it would be like 「立って死ぬべき(だ)」 or 「立って死ぬべし」, "should/must die while standing".

Comment: 細かいことですが、現代語でも「死する」という動詞が残っています。「死ぬ」に相当する単語は古文でも「死ぬ」です（ナ変）

Comment: @broccoliforest あらま、どうしましょ・・・

Comment: 「死する」が「死ぬ」の堅い言い方、ということでいいんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: So the sentence uses archaic Japanese grammar? Is べき a more modern form than べし?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, archaism means loftiness. As for べき, yes and no, for there's no word fully translates べし anymore, so we sometimes just use it as is.

Comment: @broccoliforest, not disagreeing, but how do you think べし is different from べきだ (except for the loftiness)?

Comment: @dainichi 私には、「べし」より「べきだ」のほうが口語的で現代的な感じがして、「べし」のほうが古い感じや文語的と言うか、なんか壁に貼ってある社訓みたいなのにありそうな気がします。‌（​箇条書きとかで。）日常会話で「～べし！」とか言われたら、ふざけてるのかなって思うかも・・・

Comment: @dainichi Today's べき is, in a word, _should_, while Classical べし was, among many possible translations, _shall_. ～べし／べからず _thou shalt/shalt not_ kind of wording is one of those we can't find substitutes in modern language, thus we still sometimes rely on. Maybe ～しろ／するな _Do!/Don't do!_ are fitter for those situations than べき.